# Making a action/variable change only happen once, everytime a key is pressed

Tags: java, processing

I wrote code that is supposed to remove 25 HP (health points) each time a rectangle (created by pressing the <kbd>m</kbd> key) intersects another rectangle, the enemy. Currently, the enemy looses 25HP continuously after I've pressed the <kbd>m</kbd> key only once until I press the <kbd>m</kbd> key again outside of the enemy body.

This is my damage code for the enemy. It turns white when killed, that's why I have `df1` etc. there.

```java
void damage() {

    //if (callMethod) {
    HP -=25;


    //callMethod = false;
    System.out.println(" " + HP);

    //}

    if (HP == 0) {
        df1 = 200;
        df2 = 200;
        df3 = 200;
    }
}
```

This is the code for the <kbd>m</kbd> input.

```java
void Fight() {
    if (keyPressed) {

      if (key == 'm'|| key == 'M') {
        //villkor, flytta höger, X-led.
        fill(255, 0, 0, 63);
        noStroke();
        rect(xF, yF, wF, hF);
        xFF = xF;
        yFF = yF;
        wFF = wF;
        hFF = hF;

      }
   }
}
```

Here I have my intersect code:

```java
if (g.intersect(f)) {
    f.damage();
}
```

I would appreciate any help I can get. Apologies for my bad English grammar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another `boolean` variable that tracks whether the action was already taken.

Here's a small example:

```java
boolean alreadyPressed = false;

void draw() {}

void mousePressed() {
  if(!alreadyPressed){
   background(random(255)); 
  }
  alreadyPressed = true;
}
```

You can then reset the `boolean` variable whenever you want to be eligible to detect the event again.

Comment: i tried what you just described, kind of worked out. It worked out in the sense of only taking away 25 and then stopping. But now after removing 25 i cant damage it anymore because the "alreadypressed" is set to "true". and If i try to put in a "alreadypressed = false" above it goes back to continuesly removing 25. Do you know if i need mabey to place it somewhere else for it to work or...?

Comment: @TheBigChung Think about it this way: when do you want to start checking for the key press again? That's when you should reset the value of the variable.

Comment: Aaa, it worked now. I placed it in the "m" pressed function. and then it worked. thx :)